# Reading french characters in Java

Tags: java, string, character, ascii

I have to do an assignment similar to Web Indexing. Basically I have several files (ASCII format) and I have to compute the word frequencies.

One of the file contains french characters (such as ç or è). In my output file, some of the words containing french chars are not displaying correctly and because of this I have duplicates:
I have both grimaçaient and grima��aient, I have guère and gu��re, for example.

Now, regarding the used algorithm, there is a catch. I have to do the computations in a parallel manner, which involves splitting the text files into fragments (not splitting the file into multiple files, but reading from a certain offset of the file). For each fragment, I have to check if the first word has been split between two fragments: if yes, I can ignore it, and I have to check also if the last word has been split: if yes, I have to read more characters until I reach a delimiter and save it in my buffer. I think that the weird � might be related to this part.

This is how I read the fragment:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[D]; // D is 1024
file.seek(offset);
file.readFully(buffer);
```

This is how I read the peripheral words.

For the first word:

```
file.seek(offset - 1);
byte[] buf = new byte[1];
buf[0] = file.readByte();
String first_w = new String(buf);
```

For the last word:

```
String last_word = "";
byte[] buf = new byte[1];
do
{
    buf[0] = file.readByte();
    String aux = new String(buf);
    if(isDelim(aux.charAt(0))
    {
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        last_word += aux;
    }
}while(true);
```

The � appears in some of the first words, in some of the last words, and maybe most important is the fact that if the � appears in the main part of the fragment (the one that I read with readFully), the � will appear as the first letter in the string or as the last one.

How can I solve this?

EDIT: The file is a RandomAccessFile object.

Comment: What's the file encoding, UTF-8 or ISO-8859-15? There would be some significant differences.

Comment: If the file contains ç or é, then it's not ASCII, since ASCII doesn't support those characters. Read characters as characters, using a Reader and the appropriate charset, rather than trying to read them as bytes. `new String(buf)`doesn't use the appropriate charset. It uses your default charset. Read the javadoc.

Comment: The encoding is ISO-8859 text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're reading files with `RandomAccessFile`, I fear there's not much built-in support to handle file encodings properly.

If your file is encoding in **ISO-8859-15**, it is pretty straight forward. You can use `new String(byte[], "ISO-8859-15")` in that case.

If your file is encoded in **UTF-8**, you have to deal with the fact that characters with Unicode code points > 127 are encoded with more than 1 byte. But it's simple.
If the first bit is 0 (byte value >= 0), it's a single-byte character.
If the first bit is 1 (byte value <0), it's a multi-byte character. If the second bit is 1, it's the start of a multi-byte character, if the second bit is 0, it's a data byte for a multi-byte character. You simply read all data-bytes and add them to your array.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `new String(byte[] buf)` constructor. It doesn't take into account the encoding of the bytes (and uses the platform default). Use the `new String(byte[] buf, String encoding)` and specify the correct encoding.